# SQL Server : how to enforce integrity at the end of a transaction?

Tags: sql-server, triggers, transactions

I'm having a hard time understanding how to enforce a one-to-many both-way mandatory relationship between two tables. I have two tables, roughly something like that:

```
CREATE TABLE Trips 
(
   tripID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
   starts date NOT NULL,
   ends date NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE TripDays 
(
   tripDayID int IDENTITY(1, 1),
   tripID int NOT NULL,
   date date NOT NULL,
   expenses money NOT NULL,
   foreign key ( tripDayID ) references Trips (tripID)
);
```

In general I would like for each day of the trip, from `starts` to `ends`, to have an entry in the second table. In order to do so, I've prepared two procedures which insert the data into the relevant tables, let's call them `createTrip` and `createTripDay`. In order to fill them, I first invoke the first one with the obvious parameters `starts` and `ends`, after which I invoke the second one the appropriate number of times using `tripID` which had been returned from the first procedure.

In order to ensure that the integrity is preserved at all times I created a trigger on the table `Trips` which rolls the transaction back in case when the table `TripDays` lacks the relevant entries. Unfortunately this trigger obviously can't see the changes which are yet-to-be-made by the invocations of the second procedure, because they have not been yet committed in the transaction wrapping the insertions:

```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;

  -creating the trip
   <- the trigger raises error over violation of the integrity constraints 
  -creating entries in TripDays

  COMMIT;
```

Is there any way of delaying the execution of the trigger until the end of the transaction? It's a usual `AFTER INSERT` one.

The only other solution to the problem I can come up with is creating the entries in the trigger, but then they would lack the information required to fill the `expenses` field. I'd also appreciate some alternative solutions in case of delaying the trigger being impossible. Thank you for your help.

Comment: For future reference - when using Postgres or Oracle you can defer checking constraints until just before the transaction will have been committed. Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't provide this feature despite it having been defined at least since SQL99. This allows having circular references (like a mandatory one-to-many relationship) without a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your FK is wrong (or there is a typo).  Shouldn't the FK be TripDays.tripID to Trips.tripId?

Can you provide info about your stored procs?  It seems like the proc that populates TripDays should work off of Trips, so not sure how it would violate the FK.

Comment: Sorry for not working code, I was writing it on the go, unfortunately I only have a remote access to the server. Here's the whole code:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a5539ded8084522b2fee/

Comment: I see.  So since you are inserting the days one at a time, the trigger will fire for every entry.

I think this may be the wrong approach since it also doesn't cover things like updates and deletes.  So if you updated the Trip table to change the dates, your TripDays would be wrong.

I think you should make a separate stored procedure that is used to check if the full range is filled in the table.

Or change your approach to not autofilling the TripDays table and just fill them when expenses are entered and do the date verification then in the domain.

Comment: After giving it some more thought you are right. While I could somehow implement a solution which works like I first wanted it to do, it'd be awkward. I think I'm going to go with the lazy solution of waiting for the prices to be entered, which has to happen anyway. Thank You for you time and advice.

Answer (score 0):

Earl is right about the typo

Move your code from the second sp into an update/insert trigger of the Trips should solve your problem.